# PHP : Why single pipe works in this case?

Tags: php, pipe

I have an array. Consider that `$a['info'] == 5`. So I can write :

`<?php echo $a['info'] . ' children'; ?>` to get : "5 children".

Normally, i could write

`<?php echo (isset($a['info']) ? $a['info'] : '0') . ' children'; ?>`

to get "0 children" if `$a['info'] == 0` or is not set. But

`<?php echo ($a['info'] | '0') . ' children'; ?>` works too, but I don't know why.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT** : works too with `$a['info'] ?: '0'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe is byte or operation, so

```
$val | 0
```

Equals to

```
$val ? $val : 0
```

But this code dont check if variable exists, so if it's not - NOTICE will be raised, but code will work too, becose PHP boolean cast specifications.

`isset` checks if variable exists, if it exits, even if it value is 0, `isset` return true, so code

```
echo (isset($a['info']) ? $a['info'] : '0') . ' children';
```

echo "0 children" if **variable not exits**, not if it value is **0**.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ($a['info'] | '0')
```

This is nothing but an OR operation , it will OR like this , 0 **OR** 0 = 0 , 5 **OR** 0 = 5 , so you will get the right answer .

A **single pipe** is nothing but **OR operation** .

Bitwise OR

Comment: You haven't specified *which* or operation it is.

Comment: Ok, I know OR operation. My question is just : why does it works ? Just luck ?

Comment: No luck , if the value is set it will show that , if not set means 0.

Comment: Bitwise OR and logical OR are completely different. Bitwise operations work on the bits of the numbers.